# jupyter console doesn't work on my computer anymore

Tags: python, archlinux, jupyter-console

I sometimes use jupyter console to try out things in python.
I'm running arch linux and installed everything through the arch repos.

I hadn't ran jupyter console in quite some time, but while trying to launch it, i can't get it to work anymore.
Here is the error :

```
Jupyter console 6.5.1

Python 3.10.9 (main, Dec 19 2022, 17:35:49) [GCC 12.2.0]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.10.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: 
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-7' coro=<ZMQTerminalInteractiveShell.handle_external_iopub() done, defined at /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_console/ptshell.py:839> exception=TypeError("object int can't be used in 'await' expression")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_console/ptshell.py", line 842, in handle_external_iopub
    poll_result = await self.client.iopub_channel.socket.poll(500)
TypeError: object int can't be used in 'await' expression
Shutting down kernel
```

I tried reinstalling everything through pacman in case I accidentally changed something I shouldn't, but it changed nothing.
Any tips on what could be wrong ?

Comment: Looks similar to [this issue report](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_console/issues/275) for which there is no response yet. Maybe downgrading jupyter-console some, perhaps to say 6.4.3 will make it work because similar to [here](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_console/issues/241#issuecomment-1067755548)? Any chance you have other versions of things around? That was the case [here](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_console/issues/268#issuecomment-1075191582).

Comment: Can't believe I missed the issue report, thanks, I commented on it.
The other suggestions were also good, but I tried downgrading jupyter-console to no help, and also made sure all packages were maintained by pacman and not pip. 
I did make the console work by using an older (3.7) python interpreter to launch it. We'll see how the issue goes on github

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment but I do not have the same issue. I can launch Jupyter QT Console just fine, and I have the same python version and IPython version. Just thought I would share, even though I don't use Jupyter Console. I do all my .ipynb in vscode and all other coding in neovim.  I don't know if there is a difference between the console you are talking about and QT console, but Jupyter QT Console works fine for me, just unbearably light theme :).

Comment: So there are 2 console for jupyter : qtconsole is the graphical one. console is a terminal based console. qt also works fine on my computer. Btw, if you'd like to use the QT console but just can't stand the looks, there are themes for it : `jupyter qtconsole --style=gruvbox-dark`. See the [Colors and highlighting section on this page](https://qtconsole.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)